# What are the weakest conditions for this function inequality to be true?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $h:\mathbb{R_+}\to \mathbb{R_+}$ such that, for every $t\geqslant 0$

$$ h(t) \geqslant h(0) + \int_0^t \Lambda(h(s))\ ds  $$

with $\Lambda(x) = a-bx - c x^2, \ \ \ (a,b,c\in\mathbb{R-\{0\}}$ ).

**a)** Under which conditions is true that

$$ h(t)\geqslant y(t)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall t\geqslant0 $$

with $y(t)$ the solution of $\ \ \dot{y}(t)= \Lambda(t),\ y(0)=h(0)$.

**b)** What about a general (smooth) $\Lambda:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ ?

So far, I have, as a sufficient (but not precise) condition, that $y(t)=y(0) + \int_0^t \Lambda(s)\ ds \leqslant h(0) + \int_0^t \Lambda(h(s))\ ds \iff 0\leqslant \int_0^t [\Lambda(h(s))-\Lambda(s)] \ ds  $

- Is there a way to ensure this inequality holds?
- What are the weakest conditions possible for  **a)** and/or **b)** to be true?